# Pine script: script on how to place 1 trade per session

Tags: pine-script

I am going to create a separate buy and sell strategy script. but I only want 1 trade per session. But unsure if I got coding right below

> viewed some info on var and times - as found in possible answers <as listed below>. But did not fully understand it, but posted my proposed code below
>
> ```
> var traded_today = false
>
> //use whatever hours:days for first candle of time series chart
> //using 15min here, but can be done using an input()
> first_candle = time(timeframe.period, "9:30-9:15:23456"
>
> if (first_candle)
>     traded_today := false
>     
> condition = your_condition and not traded_today
>
> if (condition)
>     traded_today := true
> ```
>
> 1. ```
>    >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>will this work <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<as it compiled ok,
>
>    var traded_today = false
>    //conditions
>
>    sessionInput1 = input.session("1700-2300")
>    InSession1(sess) => na(time(timeframe.period, sess)) == false
>    IsInSession1 = InSession1(sessionInput1)
>    barcolor(IsInSession1 ? color.black : na)
>
>
>    //conditions
>
>    baropen = open[0]
>    barlow = low[0]
>    barprev = low[1]
>    price1 =close
>
>    BuyCond1 = barprev > vPP
>    SellCond1 = barprev < vPP
>    BuyCond2 = baropen > vPP
>    SellCond2 = baropen < vPP
>
>    BuyCond3 = ta.crossunder(price1, vPP)
>    SellCond3 = ta.crossover(price1, vPP)
>
>
>    //Buy = IsInSession1 and BuyCond2 and BuyCond3
>    //Sell = IsInSession1 and SellCond2 and SellCond3
>
>
>    //trigger an alert
>
>    if (IsInSession1)
>        traded_today := false
>
>    Buy = IsInSession1 and BuyCond2 and BuyCond3 and not traded_today
>
>    if (Buy)
>        traded_today := true 
>        alert("Buy" + syminfo.ticker + "at" + str.tostring(vPP) + "\n TP" + str.tostring(vR1) + "\n SL" + str.tostring(vS1),alert.freq_once_per_bar) 
>
>
>
>
>
>    //if Buy
>        //alert("Buy" + syminfo.ticker + "at" + str.tostring(vPP) + "\n TP" + str.tostring(vR1) + "\n SL" + str.tostring(vS1),alert.freq_once_per_bar) 
>    //if Sell
>        //alert("Sell" + syminfo.ticker + "at" + str.tostring(vPP) + "\n TP" + str.tostring(vS1) + "\n SL" + str.tostring(vR1), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
>    ```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (IsInSession1)
    traded_today := false
```

This would always reset your flag as long as you are in the session and would allow new entries.

Let's organize it a little bit.

What you need to have is a flag that tells you whether you have had a trade in the current session. That is the `traded_today` variable in your code.

Then you need to figure out if you are in the selected session. I believe that is the `IsInSession1` variable in your code.

I would create another variable that would tell you whether it is the first bar of the session. If it is, you would reset `traded_today`.

You can easily do that by `is_new_session1 = not IsInSession1[1] and IsInSession1`

At last, simply and your conditions with your entry condition.

Example:

```
var traded_today = false

IsInSession1 = InSession1(sessionInput1)
is_new_session1 = not IsInSession1[1] and IsInSession1

traded_today := is_new_session1 ? false : traded_today  // If it is a new session, reset the variable. Keep its value otherwise

Buy = IsInSession1 and BuyCond2 and BuyCond3 and not traded_today

if (Buy)
    traded_today := true 
    alert("Buy" + syminfo.ticker + "at" + str.tostring(vPP) + "\n TP" + str.tostring(vR1) + "\n SL" + str.tostring(vS1),alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Comment: getting multiple alerts in the 1 session.